# Surprising side effect of (array_expr) as $var for downstream output on non/empty value of array_expr

Tags: jq

I need to extract first object matching my criterium in input stream as a variable (if any), then to process the entire stream.

Turns out, the stream becomes `empty` if there is no matches:

Input:

```
{"ID":1}
{"ID":2}
```

Code resulting in full stream:

```
[inputs] |
(
  first(.[] | select (.ID==1))
) as $match |
.
```

Code resulting in empty stream:

```
[inputs] |
(
  first(.[] | select (.ID==3))
) as $match |
.
```

(The only difference between snippets is `.ID=={1|3}`)

How can I make the whole `inputs` available to downstream filter, whether or not there is a match?

Answer (score 2):

The key point here is that `first(empty)` yields the empty stream.
So in your query, `first(.[] | select (.ID==3)) as $match` has the effect of `empty`, and thus your program is equivalent to `empty | .`, which is empty.

Unfortunately, you have not indicated what you are actually trying to do, but chances are you might want to consider something along the lines of:

```
(first(.[] | select (.ID==3)) // null) as $match`
```

---

Since @glennjackman's response has been downvoted, it is perhaps worth emphasizing that the command-line option -n must be specified if `inputs` is to be relied on for the entire input stream.

Comment: What is suprising for me is that for `inputs | (expr) as $var | .` the output becomes `empty` when `expr` results in `empty`; stays identical to `input` for any other result of `expr`. Why does JQ work that way?

Comment: If you use `debug`, you'll see that `inputs` does not become empty. As I said, the key to understanding the behavior you find perplexing is to understand how pipes work. E.g. `true | empty as $x | debug` yields empty.

Comment: Let's hope this side effect gets mention in _[Variable / Symbolic Binding Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier|...)_ section of JQ manual at some point.

Comment: @wassrubleff This is not a side effect of `as`, it is the intended effect of `|`. From the [manual documenting the pipe operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Pipe%3A%7C): "The `|` operator combines two filters [...] If the one on the left produces multiple results, the one on the right will be run for each of those results.". This perfectly includes the case where the number of times is zero, ie. if the one on the left produces no result, the one on the right will not be run. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73809588/2158479) for a simple example.

Comment: @wassribleff - There is no side-effect.  That's maybe what needs to be mentioned, though I think it's pretty clear how pipelines work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this example will help to clarify:

```bash
0 | (1,2,3) as $x | .
```

```bash
0
0
0
```

Given a single input followed by an (even unrelated) assignment that unfolds multiple times, you end up having a stream of said multitude of items (for each of which `$x` is set to one of the assigned values).

Now, replacing `(1,2,3)` with `empty`

```bash
0 | empty as $x | .
```

is no exception to that: The assignment unfolds 0 times, so you end up with a stream of 0 items as there is no value `$x` could have been set to, and in consequence no copy of the input for which `$x` could hold a value.

---

Following your example, you could envelop the filter result in something like an array, a structure that can handle any multitude of result items, including 0. In fact, with `[inputs]` you already had that array but decomposed it with the following `.[]`. Keep it by using `map` instead, so your filter can yield either an empty array or one containing the items found.

```bash
[inputs]
| map(select (.ID == 1)) as $match
| .   # yields the whole input array with $match set to [{"ID": 1}]

# or

[inputs]
| map(select (.ID == 3)) as $match
| .   # yields the whole input array with $match set to []
```

Next, when using `$match` you would presumably only extract the first value `$match[0]` which evaluates to either the first object found, or `null` if there was no match (the array was empty). In that case, as there's no need to hold an array with possibly more than just one item in it, you could tweak the assignment from above and directly set the variable to hold the first item or `null` by moving the array (brackets) outside of the capture:

```bash
[inputs]
| map(select (.ID == 1)) as [$match]
| .   # yields the whole input array with $match set to {"ID": 1}

# or

[inputs]
| map(select (.ID == 3)) as [$match]
| .   # yields the whole input array with $match set to null
```

Comment: @peak (CC:) Is there any performance difference between `(first(.[] | select (.ID==1))`, `map(select (.ID == 1)) as $match | .[0]` and `map(select (.ID == 1)) as [$match]`  if I need _only_ first match, and the input can have quite a lot of quite large objects?

Comment: @wassrubleff Own benchmark on my own machine with 1 million items (created as `[{ID:range(1000000)}]`), and selecting the last one with `select(.ID==999999)`: the `first(.[])` solution took 1.058s, the `$match[0]` solution took 1.041s, and the `as [$match]` solution took 1.028s, so no big differences regarding speed, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

I was just playing with this today. If you want `[inputs]` to contain **all** the inputs, even the first one, you either need

```bash
jq -n '[inputs] | ...'
```

or

```bash
jq '[.] + [inputs] | ...
```

or

```bash
jq '[., inputs] | ...
```

or

```bash
jq -s '...' # "dot" is an array of all the inputs
```